# How to get the country code from contact's phoneFiled?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

In the Google Contacts UI the phone numbers has country codes represented by flags.

GAS ContactsApp's [contact.getPhoneNumber()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/phone-field#getPhoneNumber()) method does not include the selected country code.

How to extract the selected country or get the phone number in international format?

[image]